macOS Catalina Patcher and media playback
I've installed the dosdude1's Catalina patcher on a late 2011 MacBook Air i7 (Apple supported this machine up to High Sierra) and while it generally works fine, there's this weird issue with media playback: every time I log back in and want to play a video in Safari or recent versions of Firefox, streaming fails, unless I restart the browser first. Any ideas what might be going on?
(Disabling hardware acceleration doesn't have any effect.)
